# FB.Init() error during gradle build unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, gradle, release, android-proguard

I am using Unity 2018.1.6f1 and facebook-unity-sdk-7.13.0. When I try to build the project using gradle, the build is completed successfully but it gives an error while calling FB.Init()

> "AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.facebook.unity.FB".

I tried the solution in the following links:
[Android ProGuard settings for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760581/android-proguard-settings-for-facebook)

I even checked whether I was using debug keyhash, which I was, but I addded release key hash and still getting the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. It works fine in debug build

Answer (score -1):

On Android publishing settings section (in the place you set the keystore stuff), there is a checkbox for User ProGuard file (at least if you are on Gradle). If you check it, Unity will make such file and put it in the project.

Then, on the `proguard` file, I added:

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; } 
-keepattributes Signature
```

And that seems to be all! 
Then I see the FB SDK initing properly both on `Debug` and `Release`:

Hope it works for you as well.